# SSIS OData Source - Not all columns visible

Tags: ssis, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I am using OData Source from SSIS Toolbox to load data out from Dynamics AX but not all columns are visible.

E.g. my entity 'ProductionInformationDVL' is available via OData and it contains the Columns 'ProductId','ProductName' and 'ProdStatus'.
But the preview of SSIS does not show the column 'ProdStatus'. I'd like to get all available columns.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does the column show when you load the table into Destination table? 
Try using Power Query to review the same Odata source. If it does not show up there too, means it does not contain the Product Status column, or the column is coming from some other entity/table in AX.

If you are getting the source columns in destination then its probably a bug in SSIS. What version are you using? 
Please give screenshots or more details..

Answer (score 0):

So far I figured out that SSIS is unable to get columns of 'enum' datatype. But why?

For example, when I access an entity with my standard browser it looks like this:
[Dynamics data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOkwL.png) The column 'LoadStatus' is visible.

But in SSIS the column is invisible even though I can filter by that column:
[SSIS OData Source Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6us8.png)

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue using SSIS 2019 and querying Azure DevOps with the odata source component. When we query using the web browsers (or fetching the `$metadata`) the enum columns are returned but not using the odata source in SSIS.

We ended writing source script components using C# and `HttpClient` for such odata queries in order to return the Azure DevOps entities containing enums.